# Capture user data from third party website

Tags: user-input, web-deployment

I want to know any broad ideas that will point me to this:
I want to capture the data that my website's user enters after being redirected to another third party website. Want to let the user authorize this before we do it as well.

How can this be done, what tools and practices are available already? What topics should I explore to accomplish this?

I am wondering - if a cookie can capture user activity on a third party website? Can I use use selenium?

Comment: By definition of "third party", that implies the data is out of your control, and cannot be returned back to you unless you tell that server to do so (which can be a security flaw, like SQL injection, or XSS)

Comment: We cant use the data from the changing DOM? after inputs?

Comment: Not all websites change DOM after input. This question itself is very vague. Maybe you should give a concrete example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all websites work - you are sending a request, and you get back a response, and optionally a session token, which could be stored in a cookie. You could use this token to communicate continuously with that third party site (such as using Selenium, or just a regular REST API, assuming that third party site allows one)

"Broad ideas" - Web scraping + APIs, or [security attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/)

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks.